# SignalR connection failing when calling through an intermittent WebApi Service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr, azure-service-fabric, api-gateway

I've an angular app, a gateway service(web api) and an asp.net core service(where the SignalR hub is present). I'm trying to connect from the angular app to SignalR hub through the gateway and the request is failing with the below error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at '(gateway)/signalR/connect/negotiate' from origin '(UI website)' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

//UI code:
this is request I'm posting from angular app.

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
             .withUrl(https://gateway/signalr/connect)
             .withAutomaticReconnect()
             .build();
```

//Gateway code:
https://gateway/signalr/connect is a post api in gateway service.

With in the gateway post api, I'm making a connection to signalr hub like below:
https://localhost:19081/(myservice)/SignalR/(myHub)

//SignalR Service:
Also added the below cors policy in my signalr startup:

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("SignalRPolicy", builder =>
                    {
                        builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                               .AllowCredentials()
                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                               .WithOrigins(<allowedorigins>);
                    }));

app.UseCors("SignalRPolicy");

app.UseAzureSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<HubClass>("/<myhub>");
            });
```

If I  directly call the SignalR hub from UI - this request is passing and connecting to signalr successfully.

Here both Gateway service and my signalr service are hosted on azure service fabric. The requirement is, all the calls from UI need to go through the gateway.

Please let me know  how I can make this work. Thank you.

Comment: What gateway are you using ?  [Ocelot](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/websockets.html#signalr) has support for signalR. Your gateway probably needs to support web sockets and map all the signalR routes.

Answer (score 0):

You must to explicit (withCredentials: false) at hub connection.

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
         .withUrl(https://gateway/signalr/connect, 
                 { skipNegotiation: false, 
                   withCredentials: false, 
                   transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets })
         .withAutomaticReconnect()
         .build();
```